# How to name a model in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

is there a "best practice" for naming the model?

I got a table called `users`.

Model-Names:
user?
users?
user_model?
usermodel?

functions: add, update, delete, check_password...

Which model name would you choose?

Comment: Codeigniter has no conventions, only a few rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Codeigntier [example](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#anatomy) uses the `name_model.php` practice. So i usually name the file `user_model.php`

Then the file contents

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_users() {
        //return all users
    }

    public function post_user($user_data) { //or create_user, your choice
       //insert user
    }

}
```

I prefer to use `get_`, `post_`, `update_`, and `delete_` for readability. This is my preference and by no means do you have to follow this approach.

Comment: For what it's worth, nowhere in the link you provided is it suggested that `{object name}_model` is a convention. There is merely one example that uses that naming style, while there are other examples that do not. Personally I think it's a horrible convention but I won't deny that it's probably the most popular one with CI users.

Comment: True, I should have chosen words more wisely.  I will update the answer

Answer (score 2):

its personal preference really, but i personally suffix models with _model so as to interfere with similarly named libraries or controllers.

Comment: This! I had a `User` model for CRUD, and a `User` controller for URLs `user/x`. Had to rename the model to `User_model`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in this scenario you could use the name User_model, although this is not a requirement and could change depending on the project's standards.

The only requirement is that the name of the file is a lowercase version of the name of the class, so your file would be named user_model.php and would contain:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

}
```